# python 2.7.9/pycharm 4/windows7: 'file' object has no attribute 'readall'

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I'm trying to write some VERY trivial thing in pycharm.

Problem:

```
sourceText = ""

with open("lang.txt", "rt") as sourceFile:
    sourceText = sourceFile.readall()

print sourceText
```

when I enter "." after "sourceFile", I get popup that offers me "readall()" method. However, when I attempt to run the script, I get"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ....languages/languages.py", line 4, in <module>
    sourceText = sourceFile.readall()
 AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readall'
```

The method is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) (I get popup, can get documentation for this method using Ctrl+Q) but it seems to be inaccessible.

I'm a bit confused.

I'd like to either:

1. **Not** receive any popups for inaccessible methods in pycharm.
2. Or figure out why I can't see it despite it being documented.

Advice?

I'm using windows 7 64 bit, and have two python 2.7.9 installations (32bit and 64bit), with 64bit being in path 1st. Pycharm is 4.0.5 community edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that `readall` is documented for the `io` module, but it's complaining about `file`, which does not have that method. You want the `read()` method to read all the data in the file in one large clump. You could also use `readlines()` which well return a list. I have the Pro 3.4 edition of PyCharm and it does not do this. I would report this as a bug to PyCharm.

Comment: Hmm... I assumed that pycharm looks up identifier before dot and file inherited methods from io or something like that (python is not my primary language)... *sigh*... so, you're saying it is most likely a bug?

Comment: It's a strange bug even if PyCharm mistakenly assumes `io.open` is the default in 2.x, because `readall` is only defined for unbuffered binary-mode access (i.e. `io.RawIOBase`), e.g. `open("lang.txt", "rb", buffering=0)`.

Comment: I agree that it's weird, but I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: Seeing as there are no more replies, I'm chalking it up as a glitch. Thanks for replying.